# url rewrite not working .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the url using htaccess and I have tried answers given on another questions here however nothing seems to be working at all I still get the original url.
this is what I have:

```
http://localhost/inbox.php?pg=2
```

I want

```
http://localhost/inbox/2
```

I already had a rule that gets rid of the .php extension in .htaccess as below and just added the last line

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /inbox.php?pg=$1//added this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the line before the last one is defined as the last one so your rule must be above that RewriteConditions. Better use this rule set:

```
RewriteRule ^/?inbox/(\d+)$ /inbox.php?pg=$1 [QSD,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

I added your needed prefix which you missed and made it mandetory that after that numbers will follow (at least one).

Comment: but still the pg is not gone

Comment: I missed the [QSD,L] that forces to remove the old query string

Comment: still I am getting `pg=2`

Comment: Let me guess you are using Apache 2.2?

Comment: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6

Comment: okay I got this working, however if the url is something like `localhost/inobx/2`, it is okay, however if I get rid of the 2 at the end I get 500 error or if I change the 2 into 2.5 I get 500. So is there a way to check using .htaccess if the parameter is empty or the variable is not integer, and redirect to inbox. I already tried checking using php however it doesn't work.

Comment: That is strange my rule does only accept numbers so if you add the dot my rule will ignore the url and the other rules will process that request.

Comment: I have no idea but it still happens, I couldn't find any help on the net about that issue. `http://localhost/inobx/` or `http://localhost/inbox/2.5` or `http://localhost/inobox/2jfg` will trigger 500 internal error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50747/discussion-between-rekire-and-user3412305)

Answer (score 0):

Apache rewrite engine is mainly used to turn dynamic url’s such as **`http://localhost/inbox.php?pg=2`** into static and user friendly url’s **`http://localhost/inbox/2`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^inbox/([^/.]+)/?$ /inbox.php?pg=$1 [L]
```

### Explanation: *How this work*

> **Call to action:** RewriteRule
>
> **Pattern:** ^inbox/([^/.]+)/?$
>
> **Rewrite:** /inbox.php?pg=$1
>
> **Command Flag:** [L]

Comment: That rule would also allow /inbox/crashme/

Comment: @rekire if URL is like `http://localhost/inbox.php?pg=crashme` then static url set /inbox/crashme/ then whats wrong?

Comment: same here too still `pg=2` is there

Comment: @user1153551 IMHO it's oblivious that only numbers are required, but okay. Is it also your intent that it will accept `/inbox/crash/4711/me` too? Just `/inbox/fail.` will not work.

Comment: @rekire as my knowledge i set rewriterule but i am great appreciate if you update my answer as per your knowledge. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^inbox/([0-9]+)/?$ inbox.php?pg=$1
```

Source: [10 Simple examples to rewrite using htaccess](http://www.myaakriti.com/web/htaccess/10-useful-ways-to-rewrite-url-using-htaccess/)