# mod_rewrite doesn't work on localhost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, xampp

I've tried to rewrite the URL of the website `foto.php` to `Aquaria.php` but for some reason it doesn't work, I'm not getting a console error or an error on the page.

I've placed the `htaccess.htaccess` file in the root directory of my `Aquaria` website.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule foto.php(.*) Aquaria.php$1 [PT]
</IfModule>
```

I've used the following links to educate myself on how to use htaccess:

1. [URL Rewriting not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074903/url-rewrite-not-working-htaccess)
2. [Rewrite URL with htaccess
       localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243975/rewriting-url-with-htaccess-local-in-xampp)
3. [Enable URL Rewriting](http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/enable-apache-rewrite-module.html)
4. [htaccess tricks and tips](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)

I've checked if there was a `#`before: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` and it wasn't there, I then went on to try changing `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride ALL` as suggested by [the third link](http://www.anmsaiful.net/blog/php/enable-apache-rewrite-module.html), this didn't work either. After researching `AllowOverride None` I read that it shouldn't be used because it may grant access to all files for every user on the website.

Using `phpinfo();` I checked if the Rewrite Module was loaded, which it was, I checked it where it says `Loaded Modules`, where I found `mod_rewrite`

TL;DR: The rewrite module doesn't give an error in the console on LocalHost, neither does it give an error on the page, I've used the links mentioned above to educate myself little by little to get to where I'am now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file name must be `.htaccess` without a filename

To rename a .htaccess file without filename,

1. Go to search
2. Type in CMD
3. Open your CMD
4. Type in: rename pathnamehere\filename.htaccess .htaccess

Comment: Yes it is, I can't remove `htaccess` infront of the . because you are required to have a file name on windows 8

Comment: Have you tried setting `AllowOverride` to none in your http.conf?

Comment: Thank you, your first answer works correctly, can you please edit this to your answer:

To create a .htaccess file without filename,
Go to search
Type in CMD
Open your CMD
Type in: rename pathnamehere\filename.htaccess .htaccess